# Check if word entered is correct

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a poem with blank lines. The blank must be changed and I have javascript created to check if the word that is entered is the correct word that should be in the poem.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
<body>
<pre id="poem">
Social Media
Relax yourself,
As I <span id = "word1" contenteditable>______</span>
through your mind
Scroll down the pages
of your spine
Reading every word 
and thought on
your <span contenteditable>____</span> like a <span contenteditable>____</span>
Stumbled Upon 
you then <span contenteditable>_______</span> onto
your looks--IGuess
I'm <span contenteditable>______</span> into you
You're my one
and only <span contenteditable>________</span>

Will you <span contenteditable>______</span> me?

</pre>
<button onsubmit = "isCorrect()"> submit </button>
<p color = "white" id = "demo"></p>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function isCorrect(){
    var word = document.getElementById("word1").value;
    if (word == "dig")
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = word;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the expected output and what you get instead.

Comment: Also, why `onsubmit` and not simply `onclick` on that button?

Comment: Your JS will only check the first blank of your input. Not the other blanks

Comment: I would expect the paragraph with id = "demo" to then say the word that was entered if it is correct. Nothing happens though

Comment: First of all the submit event will never be fired since you are not using a form.

Answer (score 0):

`word1` is a `span`, use `innerHTML` instead of `value`. And I would recommend `addEventListener` instead of `onsubmit`.

```
document.querySelector( "button" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   isCorrect();
});
function isCorrect(){
    var word = document.getElementById("word1").innerHTML;
    if (word == "dig")
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = word;
    }
}
```

Similarly, you can check the values of other `span`s as well. I would recommend putting the values as the attribute of `span` itself, for example

```
As I <span id = "word1" data-value="dig" contenteditable>______</span>
```

And verify the same as

```
var allSpans = document.querySelectorAll( span[contenteditable] );
Array.from(allSpans).forEach( s => {
   var dataValue = s.getAttribute( "data-value" );
   if (dataValue == s.innerHTML )
   {
     //code for correct value
   }
})
```

Comment: Why not outerHTML?

Comment: outerHTML will give `<span>` as well

Comment: this doesnt work either

Comment: @StevenR Instead of onsubmit, use onclick